# Pandas .fllna() not fililng in values even with inplace argument

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe (`df`) where I want to fill in missing values in certain columns.  I tried to do this like the below but they are still coming back not filled in.

```
df[
    ['incurred', 'noncatincrd', 'catincrd', 'clmcnt', 'noncatcnt', 'catcnt', 'cvrcnt', 'CMincurred'
    , 'CMcvrcnt', 'CLincurred', 'CLcvrcnt', 'PDincurred', 'PDcvrcnt', 'OLincurred', 
     'OLcvrcnt']
   ].fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I'm on pandas 0.24.2

Comment: Can you provide a small re-producible example. i.e. a small dataframe initialized in code which shows your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this on git: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14858

The way to do this is

```
df.loc[:,
    ['incurred', 'noncatincrd', 'catincrd', 'clmcnt', 'noncatcnt', 'catcnt', 'cvrcnt', 'CMincurred', 'CMcvrcnt'
   , 'CLincurred', 'CLcvrcnt', 'PDincurred', 'PDcvrcnt', 'OLincurred', 'OLcvrcnt']
] = df.loc[:,
    ['incurred', 'noncatincrd', 'catincrd', 'clmcnt', 'noncatcnt', 'catcnt', 'cvrcnt', 'CMincurred', 'CMcvrcnt'
   , 'CLincurred', 'CLcvrcnt', 'PDincurred', 'PDcvrcnt', 'OLincurred', 'OLcvrcnt']
].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0], [3, 4, np.nan, 1], [
                  np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5], [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]], columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)
df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']] = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].fillna(0)
print(df)
```

df before:

```
     A    B   C  D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5
3  NaN  3.0 NaN  4
```

df after:

```
     A    B    C  D
0  0.0  2.0  0.0  0
1  3.0  4.0  0.0  1
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  5
3  0.0  3.0  0.0  4
```